# How is these answers correct related to stacks

Tags: algorithm, stack

So I am following this algorithm course from Princeton University done through coursera. I was doing this question related to stacks. The answer baffles me. Appreciate if anyone can kindly show me where I am going wrong in this;

Question : Suppose that an intermixed sequence of push and pop operations are performed
on a LIFO stack. The pushes push the letters A through J in order; the pops
print out the return value. Which of the following output sequence(s) could occur?

Correct answer 1 : B E D C G A F I J H

Explanation : When G is pushed, both A and F are still on the stack. So, F would be popped before A.

My question : If F should appear before A, then that answer cannot be true right?

Correct answer 2 : B C E A I J H G F D

Explanation : When E is pushed, both A and D are still on the stack. So, D would be popped before A.

My Question : again D should come before A right?

Appreciate if someone can show me what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, both examples cannot happen, for the reasons you explain.  Are you sure you are reading the answers correctly?  The explanations are reasons why that output *cannot* happen, not why it can.

Comment: Hi Keith, well it was ticked as a right answer and an explanation was given. Probably some mistake. Thank you for clarifying. I thought i was missing some point.